# Implementing django_multitenant in django 4.2

Tags: django, citus, django-multitenant

I'm working on a new django 4.2 project. To implement multi-tenancy, I'm using the [django_multitenant](https://github.com/citusdata/django-multitenant) library with Citus 12.1 and PostgreSQL 16.

While defining the models I see that there is ambiguity in the recommended steps. There are multiple guides but with different suggestions.

1. https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2023/05/09/evolving-django-multitenant-to-build-scalable-saas-apps-on-postgres-and-citus/
2. https://github.com/citusdata/django-multitenant#readme

There is no clear explanation on how migrations are addressed. The former asks to write a custom migration file while the latter skipped that step.

What is the recommended way and model structure if one is implementing `django_multitenant` in a new django 4.2 project using citus 12.1 and postgresql 16 using the default row-based sharding option?